# Assign log depending user department change history

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to create a select statement that get information from a MS SQL Server based on user printing. The problem is, each user has an specific department id and we have a changing history from that department. So my report must be smart enough to allocate printing from a specificperiod, like 1 month, and, if that user had it department changed, it will allocate those printing to the correct department. (for eg, the first 15 days his dept was IT and the other day it was changed to Development)...

Let me show my database:

USER

```
id       name              department_id

1        John Doe          2
```

DEPARTMENT

```
id          name

1           T.I

2           Dev

3           R&D

4           FRONT

5           BACK
```

USER_DEPARTMENT_HISTORY

```
id  user_id  department_id start_date   end_date

1   1        1             1900-01-01   2017-11-10

2   1        2             2017-11-10   2017-11-15 

3   1        3             2017-11-15   2999-01-01
```

LOG

```
id          user_id     pages       printed_on

1           1           5           2017-11-10 00:00:00.000

2           1           7           2017-10-12 00:00:00.000

3           1           3           2017-10-10 00:00:00.000

4           1           3           2017-09-10 00:00:00.000

5           1           3           2017-09-11 00:00:00.000
```

It would be a nice approach IF we shouldn't consider it changing department history

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you show the results you want?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `joins`  as follows

```
select  u.name as [user] ,d.name as department,l.pages,l.printed_on
from user u
inner join USER_DEPARTMENT_HISTORY dh on u.id = dh.[user_id] 
inner join Department d on d.id = dh.department_id
inner join LOG l on l.[user_id] = u.id and printed_on>=[start_date] and printed_on <end_date
```

**Complete Script:**

```
create table #user
( id int,
[name] varchar(25),
department_id int
)

insert into #user
values(1,'John Doe',2)


create table #Department
(
id int,
name varchar(25)
)


insert into #DEPARTMENT
values(1,'T.I'),
(2,'Dev'),
(3,'R&D'),
(4,'FRONT'),
(5,'BACK')

create table #USER_DEPARTMENT_HISTORY
(
id  int ,
[user_id]   int,
department_id int,
start_date   date,
end_date date
)


insert into #USER_DEPARTMENT_HISTORY
values(1,1,1,'1900-01-01','2017-11-10'),
(2,1,2,'2017-11-10','2017-11-15'),
(3,1,3,'2017-11-15','2999-01-01')

create table #LOG
(
id  int ,
[user_id]   int,
pages int,
printed_on   datetime
)

insert into #LOG
values(1,1,5,'2017-11-10 00:00:00.000'),
(2,1,7,'2017-10-12 00:00:00.000'),
(3,1,3,'2017-10-10 00:00:00.000'),
(4,1,3,'2017-09-10 00:00:00.000'),
(5,1,3,'2017-09-11 00:00:00.000')


select  u.name as [user] ,d.name as department,l.pages,l.printed_on
from #user u
inner join #USER_DEPARTMENT_HISTORY dh on u.id = dh.[user_id] 
inner join #Department d on d.id = dh.department_id
inner join #LOG l on l.[user_id] = u.id and printed_on>=[start_date] and printed_on <end_date

drop table #user
drop table #USER_DEPARTMENT_HISTORY
drop table #Department
drop table #LOG
```

Comment: It doesn't work because ir duplicates all lines... check your output, all lines are duplicated according to number of user department history..

Comment: Please update your question with expected output. it is not clear what your are looking for. This solution shows how to get department of  a user on a printing date.